# Why hydra showing this error [ERROR] could not connect to ssh://192.168.0.1:22?

Tags: ssh, brute-force, hydra

I am using hydra to bruteforce my router admin page. By scanning with nmap it is showing port 22 ssh is open and when i use medusa it is bruteforcing properly but with hydra i am using this command :

`hydra -l admin -p admin  ssh://192.168.0.1 -t 2`

But it is giving me this error:

```
[ERROR] could not connect to ssh://192.168.0.1:22 - kex error : no match for method kex algos: server
[diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1], client
[curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256]
```

Why it is so? metasploit bruteforce, nmap bruteforce and medusa all are working good but not hydra?

Comment: In the error message that you posted, see the list of key exchange algorithms that the server supports, then see the list of key exchange algorithms that the client (in this case, hydra) supports.  Note how there are none in common.  Because of this, the client (hydra) cannot create a secure connection to the server.

Comment: Also, you are saying that you want to use hydra to brute-force your router admin page.  The local web server running on your router, which serves the admin web interface, likely runs on port 80 or port 443, but not on port 22.  Port 22 is usually used for SSH.

Answer (score 0):

It should be because of `ssh` working in Strong Security mode.

---

**Solution:** In order to connect with legacy key exchange algorithms (such as `diffie-hellman-*-sha1`), try to switch `ssh` to wide compatibility mode.

- It can be done by adding the following to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

```
Host *
    Ciphers 3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
    KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
    HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
    PermitLocalCommand yes
```

---

References:

1. [thc-hydra: SSH Wide Compatability Mode Unsupported [SOLUTION]](https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/issues/792)
2. [Kali Linux – SSH client: Wide Compatibility vs Strong Security](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/ssh-configuration/)

Comment: Now it is giving this error:

Comment: `[ERROR] could not connect to ssh://192.168.0.1:22 - ssh_set_client_kex: Out of memory
`

Comment: @MuhammadUmerAsif I've updated the answer (file contents only). Please replace the code in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file and try again.

Comment: Reasoning: it looks like `libssh` (`ssh` dependency) doesn't support `+`,`-`,`^` signs in the config.